# Trouble changing a function in javascript using ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm using the below coding to change a function in my button element.

html:

```
 <input id="btnCall" type="button" value="Next Call"  onclick="Call();"/>
```

Originally the btnCall will run Call() function. Under some condition, I will change the function inside btnCall using below coding.
js:

```
document.getElementById("btnCall").onclick = function() {txCall();};
ChgText("btnCall", "Transfer Call");
```

I'm using ie11 in windows 7 and the above javascript function sometimes can work sometimes cannot work. Anybody know why? Or is there a better way to change a button onclick function that will work in ie?

Comment: A better way would be to not use an inline html `onclick` attribute and just use `document.getElementById("btnCall").onclick = Call` or `document.getElementById("btnCall").onclick = txCall` as required. Or bind the onclick to a third function that has some logic to decide whether to call `Call()` or `txCall()`. (By the way, does your mention of IE, specifically, mean that it works in other browsers?)

Comment: are you sure the code to change what btnCall does is being executed, and that it is executed after the element is defined?

Comment: Jaromanda X, yes it is execute. Because the ChgText function got run and I can see the button label changed to "Transfer Call".

Comment: nnnnn, I have not tried other browser yet... because it requires a long time to test it. I tried run it around 100 times, maybe around 80 times can work. the other 20 times cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to have inline functions/styles. Since you already have and ID for your button, you may consider

**HTML**

```
<input id="btnCall" type="button" value="Next Call" />
```

**JS**

Use switch statement for you default code

```
function init() {
    document.getElementById("btnCall").onclick = function() {
        switch(expression) {
            case n1:
            // code for case 1
            break;

            case n2:
            // code for case 1
            break;

            default:
            // your default code will run here
        }
    };
}

window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the condition check and calls into another function:

```
<input id="btnCall" type="button" value="Next Call"  onclick="myCall()"/>

function myCall() {
    if (condition) 
        (myCall2())
    else
        (myCall3())
```

Changing the onClick of the button is probably not the greatest way to go.

Comment: Oh... is it? I was thinking not to change the original Call() function. So, that means ie really have problem when comes to changing the onclick function?

Comment: IE has alot of problems, but if it's working some of the time it might be another mistake in your code. If you pastebin it I/we can check for you and change your awnser accordingly if we find anything.